# Using monit to monit multiple delayed_jobs processes

Tags: delayed-job, monit, process-monitoring

I've looked at other SO questions about using the `monit` utility to monitor `delayed_jobs` processes, and none of them really provide a satisfactory answer to a "real-world" situation.

The issue is that `monit` is looking for a singular pidfile to monitor a process, and if you do a single `delayed_job` process, then everything works fine to start/stop `delayed_jobs` via `monit`:

```
# .monitrc config file
check delayed_jobs with pidfile path/to/app/tmp/pids/delayed_jobs.pid
  program start = "RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job start"
  program stop = "RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job stop"
```

However, in any real-world application, you will have multiple `delayed_jobs` processes that work on different queues.

```
# .monitrc config file
check delayed_jobs with pidfile path/to/app/tmp/pids/delayed_jobs.pid
  program start = "RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job --pool=mailers:1 --pool=default:2 --pool=priority:1 start"
  program stop = "RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job stop"
```

This will actually start 4 separate `delayed_jobs` processes, and each process will work on the respective queues listed in the `pool` option.

This does not generate a single `path/to/app/tmp/pids/delayed_jobs.pid` file, but instead generates multiple pidfiles, one for each separate process, and I don't know how to get `monit` to handle that.

For the "stop" action, I could execute a `pkill -f delayed_jobs`, and that works. So I can have the "start" action generate multiple processes, and the "stop" action can kill them all, but then the issue is that `monit` flags this process as `does not exist` because it doesn't have a single `pidfile` to monitor.

The brute force approach is having a separate `monit` process for every single `delayed_jobs` queue, and if I have multiple processes for a single queue, then prefix them with the process index, so I would have pidfiles like:

```
delayed_jobs.priority.pid
delayed_jobs.mailers.pid
delayed_jobs.default_1.pid
delayed_jobs.default_2.pid
```

This "works", but seems extremely verbose and painful to maintain.

Is there a cleaner way for `monit` to monitor a collection of processes, in this case specifically `delayed_jobs`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is, Monit does not support this, sorry.

> Is there a cleaner way for monit to monitor a collection of processes, in this case specifically delayed_jobs?

Your "brute force" approach is the only way to start/stop/handle a single job in a list of jobs.